# Accessing Dynamic Variable to Perform Operations

Tags: python, global-variables

I have created dynamic variables like this:

```
for n in range(0, entity_count):
globals()['node%s' % n] = Node(list_for_nodesType[n], name=list_for_nodesName[n])
```

Now I want to access these variables as I want to perform an operation where I need variable1 and variable2 at the same time. While using the above method I can't access variable2 as it says I can't concatenate into a string. How can I access these variables?

Note: Number of variables may vary according to the input string.

Comment: If you're doing things like this then there's almost always a better way. Why not just have a dictionary that you enter the items in to, making it simply `nodes[n] = Node(list_for_nodesType[n], name=list_for_nodesName[n])`? Or a list given that they're all sequential IDs.

Comment: I'll try it by dictionary and will get back with a solution..